# genisoimage/mkisofs making isos

Tags: linux, disk-image

I am trying to reproduce a .iso (of clonezilla), needed a proprietary driver to work.  I had to unpack, unsquashfs, add a driver, resquash, re-iso the distribution....

Now, I am trying to re-create a bootable .iso :)  An iso that will not be written to DVDs, but to usbs rather, or be booted into xen/kvm/etc...

Every attempt has failed so far... here is the general syntax I am using:

```
>$ cat makemeanewiso.sh
genisoimage -r -v -V "CASPER" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o ../bootme.iso .
```

If I download a clonezilla image, and do the following to it :

```
mount -o loop clonezilla.iso tmp/
mkdir tmp2 && cp -Rf tmp/* tmp2/
run the makemeanewiso.sh from here
```

Then, the iso does not boot with a xen DomU, but boots just fine if burnt to a DVD :)
Can someone please help me out with mkisofs options to make a good iso?

**Video:**
    http://youtu.be/_oQglMao8FA

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just install it with Xen without changing the ISO, then edit the files you need after it's installed, then make a clonezilla image for future use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on a usb, try making a .img of it and using a free program online to burn it to a USB drive. ISO files don't like booting from USB.

Comment: not booting from USB, check out the video man...  just unpacking an .iso, repacking it, and trying to start a xen guest with it.

looking for a good/quick way to test my work